# How to create/write file in the root of the Android device?

Tags: android, file-io

I found out that you can use something like this to create a file:

```
FileOutputStream  fs = openFileOutput("/test.in", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
String s = "[Head]\r\n";
s += "Type=2";
byte[] buffer = s.getBytes();
fs.write(buffer);
fs.close();
```

When running the above code I get an IllegalArgumentException stating:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   File /test.in contains a path
>   separator

and I'm guessing the "/" is not appreciated. I wanted the "/" since I need to write the file to the root directory of the device, as stated in the API in trying to follow:

> A request is a textfile (UNICODE) with
>   the file extension ".in". The
>   application reads and parses the .in
>   file when it's placed in root
>   directory on the mobile device.

Question is: how do I place a file in the root-directory? I have been looking around for an answer, but haven't found one yet.

Comment: see this http://www.anddev.org/working_with_files-t115.html

Comment: As a 3rd party application developer, you cannot place a file in the root directory, period.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Context.openFileOutput is meant to be used for creating files private to your application. they go in your app's private data directory. you supply a *name*, not a path: "name The name of the file to open; can not contain path separators".

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput(java.lang.String, int)

as for your question, you can't write to / unless you're root:

my-linux-box$ adb shell ls -l -d /
drwxr-xr-x root     root              2010-01-16 07:42 
$

i don't know what your API is that expects you to write to the root directory, but i'm guessing it's not an Android API and you're reading the wrong documentation ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Its the only API available to "communicate" with this Application. You communicate by creating text-files in the root directory as quoted above. So its not the wrong documentation - its the only one that exists. I will contact them and ask how they expect that to work on Android =)

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't need you to write to the root directory of the SD card?

Answer (score 4):

You can add files with path in private directory like that

```
    String path = this.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir() + "/testDir/";
    File file = new File(path);
    file.mkdirs();
    path += "testlab.txt";
    OutputStream myOutput;
    try {
    myOutput = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path,true));
    write(myOutput, new String("TEST").getBytes());
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Where does "write(OutputStream, Byte[])" get declared? I had to use myOutput.write(Byte[]) instead to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem today

**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File /test.txt contains a path separator**

and when i tried the following it worked.

```
           File inputFile = new File("/storage/new/test.txt");
           FileInputStream isr = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
           DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(isr);

           if(!inputFile.exists()){

                   Log.v("FILE","InputFile not available");

            }
           else
           {
               while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
               {
                   ........ //parse 
               }
           }
```

(Btw, I was getting this problem outside /root dir and while searching i saw this post)

Comment: Thx for the answer. If I ever get my hands into android development again, I will try it out =)