# Writing a mapping application with GPS API?

Tags: android

I am thinking to try write a map application for Android... But there is something I am getting confused.

From [android document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/package-summary.html), I know that we should have an API for getting the mobile phone location?

During my research, there is a lot of people talked about using [Google Map API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html), and I heard something about they have [API restriction because Google does not own all the data needed to make their maps and do their navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088863/offline-navigation-software-for-android-what-is-out-there) .

Here is what I am getting confused:

1. Is using Mobile's GPS is free? (That's mean I should able to write a application that uses the GPS to get the mobile location without the use of internet)
2. I don't really understand how Google Map have API restriction because of data right...  What is that data right?  So if I write a map application that uses GPS, does that apply to me as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Using the mobile GPS is free. It's the same as the other services provided by the OS. The accuracy depends on the Android device.
2. Google Maps API has certain restrictions on the usage of the map data, the geocoding data that they provide and other stuff as well. For example, you can not show the result of geocoding searches without showing a Google Map on the same screen. The map images cannot be used for commercial purposes outside the API. For ex. printing the images and selling them as separate maps.

The restrictions apply to you if you use the Maps API. What application are you thinking of building though?

Comment: But what if I am not using the Google Map API? I am thinking to make one just for fun and try learn writing some Android App. See if is possible to say i.e capture some map images from google or from somewhere into image files (or say make my own map image), store into the device and map the co-ordinates to the map images, then all I used is just the GPS to get the co-ordinates. Does the restrictions apply to me as well?

Comment: You can't use the Google Map images outside of the API. If you get images from somewhere else legally, you are free to map the geopoints from the geocoding service to your images. Usage of the user's location permission is granted by the user himself and not by any intermediary. You however have to use it responsibly. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can get the co-ordinates without using the internet. Converting this to a street address, or getting map tiles, will require internet access.
2. The data right is the ownership/licensing of the data. For example DVD, a distributor in one region is licensed by the copyright holder to sell you a copy. You have different rights to the distributor, who has different rights to the copyright holder.

Comment: When you talk about converting the co-ordinates to street address, is it done by my side? So say.. like x, y, z then I will need to have a database to find the street address etc?  So... if I want to do it without internet, I will need a database that has all street address etc in my local device...?

Comment: The default GeoCoding on Android is the Google APIs, which is done by online lookups. For offline-only, you'll need a local DB. AFAIK, there aren't any free, offline databases, and you need to buy regionally (or create your own)