# Problem Writing Files problem in Android Emulator

Tags: java, android, io

I am trying to write some simple data to External storage using the following code. I am missing something here but not sure what. Thanks

RobD

```
public class TimeCard extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        final EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
        final EditText edittext1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText02);
        final EditText edittext2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText03);
        final EditText edittext3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText04);
        final String inputString = edittext + "/n" + edittext1 + "/n"+  edittext2 + "/n" + edittext3;
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {               
              //Do it
              CreateFile(inputString);
              //Let them know it
              Toast.makeText(TimeCard.this, "You are Clocked In", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


        });
    }
    //Write to SD Card
 public void CreateFile(String InputString){        

     File SDCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();  
     String FILENAME = SDCard + "/time_card.txt";

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            fos.write(InputString.getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
   }
```

Comment: What is the problem? Do you get an Exception?

Comment: Stacktrace or it didn't happen.

Comment: Can you track at which line you have an error? If this is an emulator with Eclipse, then you should be able to check it via LogCat window.

Answer (score 3):

I tried running your code, and the error is caused by the way you use the `openFileOutput(String name, int mode)` method. Looking inside LogCat, I can see the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File /mnt/sdcard/time_card.txt contains a path separator
```

This pointed me in the direction of the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079766/how-to-create-write-file-in-the-root-of-the-android-device), which will probably solve your problem as well:

> Context.openFileOutput is meant to
>   be used for creating files private to
>   your application. They go in your
>   app's private data directory. You
>   supply a name, not a path

The [documentation for openFileOutput](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) also indicates this about the name parameter of the function:

> The name of the file to open; can not
>   contain path separators.

For future references, when you experience problems like this, it is absolutely vital that you learn how to use the tools available to you, such as LogCat. Without them, you'll have a hard time figuring out what is wrong. So I recommend reading up a bit on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell when you don't show what kind of error message you get. But my first guess is that you have forgotten to include the [`WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) permission in your [AndroidManifest.xml](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) file.

Comment: Thanks Nailuj Sorry about that- this is the exception the emulator threw "The Application (Process.AppName) has stopped unexpectedly, please try again" I will try adding the permission

Comment: @RobD: "The application has stopped unexpectedly..." doesn't tell us anything that allows us to help you. You should look at the output from LogCat (in Eclipse: Window>Show View>Other>Android>LogCat) and see if you can get a detailed stack trace with your error. You should also edit your original question to include this, so that others more easily can help you as well.

Comment: Logcat isnt doing anything and its not throwing exceptions maybe it its writing the the thing but I can't find it on the emulator? There seems to be no way to get to the external storage???

Comment: @RobD: LogCat works just fine. See my other answer for how to solve your problem.