# Writing a text file to SDCard gives a IllegalArgumentException in Android

Tags: android, file, android-sdk-2.1

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android write to sd card folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551821/android-write-to-sd-card-folder)

Writing a File with this Code:

```
public void writeFile(String data){
try { // catches IOException below
final String TESTSTRING = new String(data+"-");


String path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
    + "/test.txt";
FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput(path,
                                        MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut); 

// Write the string to the file
osw.write(TESTSTRING);
/* ensure that everything is
 * really written out and close */
osw.flush();
osw.close();

}catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Error Generated by Above Code:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File /sdcard/test.txt contains a path separator
```

I couldn't find what's wrong with this code.

Comment: Check this answer same problem solved http://stackoverflow.com/q/2079766/689853

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[openFileOuput()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileInput%28java.lang.String%29) doesn't accept paths, only a file name.

Answer (score 1):

`openFileOutput` is is used for creating private files for the application which will be saved in the application's private directory.That means you need to send a **file name** to the method not the whole path.

And also make sure that you have the  [WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml` .