# Folder created instead of a file

Tags: android, file-io

I want to create a file in a defined directory, i tried this two codes but the first just creates folders and the other output an exception: no such file or directory:
First code:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                 +File.separator
                                 +"carbu" 
                                 +File.separator
                                 +"install"); 
                            file.mkdir();
```

Then i added this code hopefully to create the file:

```
File file2 = new File("/carbu/install/","voitu");
file2.createNewFile();
```

Can anyone please try to help me ?
Thank you very much :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the most simple solution, working at 100% ;)

```
File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/jetpack/install");
                    dir.mkdirs();
                    File file = new File(dir, "wipe");
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this in your Activity:

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(YOUR_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
oos.writeInt(5);
oos.flush();
```

This will create file if it isn't exist. Of course you should close `oos` and `fos`.

Comment: And where can i put the path of "YOUR_FILE_NAME" ?

Comment: Write "/carbu/install/voitu" instead of `YOUR_FILE_NAME`

Comment: I have this logcat message(the file does not create :( ): 07-28 15:18:46.946: DEBUG/Excep_ERROR(10652): File /carbu/install/voitu/ contains a path separator

Comment: Ok, right. Do you have to create file in a directory? If you just write `voitu` instead of `YOUR_FILE_NAME` it will work. If you have to create file in a directory let me know and I will search in my earlier codes.

Comment: I just have 2 directories: /carbu/install and want to create on it an empty file. Waiting for your response.Thank you very much :).

Comment: Sorry, I remembered wrong. You can't give path in `openFileOutput`. But why you want to use directories? Just use the method by passing filename.

Comment: I really don't understand whay you mean, sorry. the method by passing filename ? how ?

Comment: Try this: `openFileOutput("voitu", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` File will be created in root directory of application. You can't see it physically. Then you can read the file by using `openFileInput("voitu")`

Comment: I don't want to make that but when created i can then copy it the to desired path in SDCARD. Right ?

Comment: You can't copy it physically. If you want to write file to sdcard try this:http://androidgps.blogspot.com/2008/09/writing-to-sd-card-in-android.html

Answer (score 0):

have you tried:

```
  File f=new File("myfile.txt");
  if(!f.exists())
  {
    f.createNewFile();
  }
```

In you example you are only giving the pathname to the file but you are not defining the type and the name of the new file.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Also try following:

```
String FILENAME = "/carbu/install/test.txt";
String string = "hello world!";

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close()
```

got the above example from: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: I have this logcat error : 07-28 15:08:08.075: DEBUG/Excep_ERROR(8887): No such file or directory

Comment: in your current directory for this particular example. you can change it to new File("/carbu/install/test.txt");

Comment: Why i have this error ? 07-28 15:23:02.646: DEBUG/Excep_ERROR(11227): File /carbu/install/test contains a path separator

Comment: Can you please post your code and the entire error message you are receiving.

Comment: Related question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079766/how-to-create-write-file-in-the-root-of-the-android-device

Comment: Thank you but this didn't help me :(. Don't know why it's stucking :\\

Answer (score 0):

```
  try {
        File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        if (root.canWrite()){
            File gpxfile = new File(root, "gpxfile.gpx");
            FileWriter gpxwriter = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(gpxwriter);
            out.write("Hello world");
            out.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Could not write file " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Here is the solution, but don't know how to add other directories than "root" ?

Answer (score 0):

While you were careful in constructing the path correctly in the first segment, you just hard-coded the wrong path in the second part.  Ensure you use the correct path, possibly as follows:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                                 +File.separator
                                 +"carbu" 
                                 +File.separator
                                 +"install";
File file = new File(path); 
file.mkdir();

File file2 = new File(path + File.separator + "voitu");
file2.createNewFile();
```