# IllegalArgumentException while reading a video file from External Stroage

Tags: android, illegalargumentexception, android-external-storage

I have a problem that I am getting IllegalArgumentException while reading a video file from sdcard. I don't know why? Please suggest me the right solution for the same.

**ErrorStack:**

```
11-03 18:56:18.733: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24192): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-03 18:56:18.733: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24192): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.TestCryptoActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File /mnt/sdcard/E0022505.mp4 contains a path separator
11-03 18:56:18.733: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24192):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
11-03 18:56:18.733: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24192):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
11-03 18:56:18.733: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24192):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-03 18:56:18.733: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24192):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-03 18:56:18.733: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24192):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-03 18:56:18.733: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24192):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-03 18:56:18.733: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24192):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-03 18:56:18.733: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24192):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-03 18:56:18.733: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24192):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-03 18:56:18.733: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24192):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-03 18:56:18.733: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24192):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-03 18:56:18.733: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24192):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-03 18:56:18.733: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24192): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File /mnt/sdcard/E0022505.mp4 contains a path separator
11-03 18:56:18.733: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24192):     at android.app.ContextImpl.makeFilename(ContextImpl.java:1602)
11-03 18:56:18.733: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24192):     at android.app.ContextImpl.openFileInput(ContextImpl.java:399)
11-03 18:56:18.733: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24192):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileInput(ContextWrapper.java:152)
11-03 18:56:18.733: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24192):     at com.example.TestCryptoActivity.onCreate(TestCryptoActivity.java:29)
11-03 18:56:18.733: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24192):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-03 18:56:18.733: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24192):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
```

**Code:**

```
    try {
        is = this.openFileInput(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/E0022505.mp4");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] b = new byte[2097152];
try {
        while ((bytesRead  = is.read(b)) != -1) {
           bos.write(b, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
try {
        String byteString = new String(bytes,"UTF-8");
        System.out.println("the bytes array of video:"+byteString);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: @ have you wrote permission in menifest file ?

Comment: Yes Dear, it is already done.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079766/how-to-create-write-file-in-the-root-of-the-android-device

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963535/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-contains-a-path-separator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Context.openFileInput` will not allow path separators because it is only to be used for private files in the application's context.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileInput(java.lang.String)

*Open a private file associated with this Context's application package for reading.*

You could open that file another way (File, FileInputStream, etc), since it is on the sdcard, but you can't use openFileInput for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this method opens a file in the `private data` area of application. You cannot open any files in subdirectories in this area . So use a `FileInputStream` or such.

Hope it helps.