# Android: Replace image saved in interna storage

Tags: android, image

I'm trying to replace an image in the internal storage of the phone with another. But i've an error with the path.That's the code:

```
private String saveToInternalSorage(Bitmap bitmapImage)
    {

        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
        // path to /data/data/yourapp/app_data/imageDir
       File directory = cw.getDir("data/data/com.aviary.android.sample/files/cdsv2/mypackage/pack_content/original-bolt-medium.png", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

       // Create imageDir
       File mypath=new File(directory,"original-bolt-medium.png");

       FileOutputStream fos = null;
       try {           

           fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);

      // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to the OutputStream
           bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
           fos.close();
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return directory.getAbsolutePath();
    }
```

That's the error:

```
 12-12 16:46:43.703: E/AndroidRuntime(19190): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-12 16:46:43.703: E/AndroidRuntime(19190): Process: com.aviary.android.sample, PID: 19190
12-12 16:46:43.703: E/AndroidRuntime(19190): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.aviary.android.sample/com.aviary.android.sample.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File app_file: /data/data/com.aviary.android.sample/files/cdsv2/com.aviary.sticker.53d185cc6b76fe302f001cde/pack_content/original-bolt-medium.png contains a path separator
```

Comment: Hope following will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7995757/illegalargumentexception-while-reading-a-video-file-from-external-stroage

Comment: Check this one too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963535/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-contains-a-path-separator