# SQLIte java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to create database in `External Micro SD Card` not in SD Card .

It is showing this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File mounted/extSdCard/mytest contains a path separator
```

I am passing this path.

The same works for SD Card .but not for my Extenally Micro sd card.

```
public SDcardDatabase(final Context context) {
        super(context,Environment.getExternalStorageState()+"/extSdCard/mytest", null, 1);
    }
```

I am writing data like this:-

```
public void saveData(View v) {
        SQLiteDatabase sqldb = null;
        SDcardDatabase mydb = new SDcardDatabase(this);
        sqldb = mydb.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues insertData = new ContentValues();
        insertData.put(SDcardDatabase.NAME, etname.getText().toString());
        insertData.put(SDcardDatabase.ADDRESS, etadd.getText().toString());
        insertData.put(SDcardDatabase.CITY, etcity.getText().toString());

        sqldb.insert("mylistdata", SDcardDatabase.NAME , insertData);

        sqldb.close();
        Toast.makeText(this,"Data saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File mounted/extSdCard/mytest contains a path separator
```

you should go to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079766/how-to-create-write-file-in-the-root-of-the-android-device), which will probably solve your problem as well:

> You should
>   supply a name of File, not Full path as your Argument.

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) also indicates this about the name parameter of the function:

> The name of the file to open can not
>   contain path separators.

Comment: if i follow your way it ll create in sd card which default path.