# save file in root directory of rooted android device

Tags: android, createfile, rooted-device

My android is rooted device.I want to store file in root `directory/data/logs`.How will I give path of the file in code.I'm writing `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()/data/logs`,then It is saving in internal memory of device not the root directory.My app will be the **system app** in device so  I have all the permissions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079766/how-to-create-write-file-in-the-root-of-the-android-device

Comment: try using `data/logs` insted of `getExternalStorageDirectory()/data/logs`

Comment: @JaiprakashSoni this will store the logs in internal memory I want to store it in android device root directory

Comment: @JaiprakashSoni I tried /data/logs it is working thanks .Problem is with the permission inlogs folder i have gave it 777 permission to this directory.now it worked